# Objective c Memory Leak related Questions

Tags: xcode, memory-leaks, uikit

1.**X-Code -> Run -> Run with Performance Tool -> Leaks**  i am getting a memory leak like Responsible Library :**UIKit** Responsible Frame:**UIKeyBoardInputManagerClassForIn**.When i traced it does not point to my code instead it points to some frame works.Is this issue of my code? or any chance of leak from apple's frame work?

Comment: 2.Responsible Library : **EventKit** Responsible Frame: **+[EKEvent storeClosed:]** when traced pointing to **dyld_stub_objc_msgSend** -> int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    
    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
   **int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil);(->100%)**
    [pool release];
    return retVal;
}

Comment: 3. Responsible Library : **Foundation** Responsible Frame: **+[NSAutoReleasePool]** tracing doesn't point to my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue related to  the frameworks.Not in your code.So it can't so in your code.So asper my knowledge no need to worry.

Comment: Is there any way to make sure these leaks are not from my code because some where i learnt that Apple prefer "No Memory Leak concept". Please help me out **importantly i am running this on simulator since i could not find the way to check on device**

Answer (score 2):

In X-Code 3.2 I connected iPhone device and the clicked **Build & Analyze** the right clicked on product/press **cmnd+shift+(A/B)** you can see many potential leaks **this is static analysis but it is showing potential leaks caused only by my code**.Hope this would be helpful for some one.

Comment: You should have edited your original question. But this is marked as answer anyway so I suggest opening a new one with your code embedded. No code = no way to answer.

Comment: ya sure .. since this looked like a solution i posted it as an answer...thnks anyways :)